# HTMLPurifier is not removing script-tag

Tags: php, xss, opencart2.x, htmlpurifier

I have tried a lot and tired now. So want to know why this code([HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)) is not removing script tag.

This is my opencart 2.1.0.2 controller->register.php

```
        $custmer_data = $this->request->post; // get all post-data
        ///////////////// html purifier ////////////
        $log_file_name = "Reg_LOGs.log";
        $logger = new Log($log_file_name); //just passed the file name as file_name.log
        $logger->write($custmer_data);
        $logger->write($custmer_data['firstname']);
        $logger->write($custmer_data['lastname']);
      if(@require_once('htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php'))
      {
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
        $config->set('Core.AggressivelyRemoveScript', true);
        $allowedElements = [
        'p[style]',
        'br',
        'b',
        'strong',
        'i',
        'em',
        's',
        'u',
        'ul',
        'ol',
        'li',
        'span[class|data-custom-id|contenteditable]',
        'table[border|cellpadding|cellspacing]',
        'tbody',
        'tr',
        'td[valign]',
    ];

    $config->set('HTML.Allowed', implode(',', $allowedElements));

    $def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
    $def->addAttribute('span', 'data-custom-id', 'Text');
    $def->addAttribute('span', 'contenteditable', 'Text');
        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
        $test_f = $purifier->purify($custmer_data['firstname']);
        $test_l = $purifier->purify($custmer_data['lastname']);
        $logger->write($test_f);
        $logger->write($test_l);
      }
        ///////////////// html purifier ends ////////////
```

I enter values for firstname & lastname like:

firstname : `<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<a onclick=&quot;script:al&quot;>L</a>" placeholder="First Name" id="input-firstname" class="form-control">`

lastname : `<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<a href=&quot;javascript:alert('Hello Stack Overflow')&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:alert('onclick')&quot;>Link with javascript</a>" placeholder="Last Name" id="input-lastname" class="form-control">`

**Before Applying HTMLPurifier the output is :**

$logger->write($custmer_data['firstname']); is written as `2020-07-23 8:36:33 - &lt;a onclick=&quot;script:al&quot;&gt;L&lt;/a&gt;`
and

$logger->write($custmer_data['lastname']); is written as `2020-07-23 8:36:33 - &lt;a href=&quot;javascript:alert('Hello Stack Overflow')&quot; onclick=&quot;javascript:alert('onclick')&quot;&gt;Link with javascript&lt;/a&gt;`

**After Applying HTMLPurifier the output is :**

$logger->write($custmer_data['firstname']); is written as `2020-07-23 8:36:33 - &lt;a onclick="script:al"&gt;L&lt;/a&gt;`
and

$logger->write($custmer_data['lastname']); is written as `2020-07-23 8:36:33 - &lt;a href="javascript:alert('Hello Stack Overflow')" onclick="javascript:alert('onclick')"&gt;Link with javascript&lt;/a&gt;`

So its not removing script tag at all.

Please help me in this.

library i use is : http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 2):

### Why is HTML Purifier doing what you observe?

I have good news: The problem you're observing is actually that there *is no* script tag.

To take the logged value of `firstname` as an example, `&lt;a onclick=&quot;script:al&quot;&gt;L&lt;/a&gt;` is perfectly well escaped HTML that is entirely harmless if you put it onto a HTML page - it renders, visibly, to the end user, as the *text*:

```
<a onclick="script:al">L</a>
```

It *doesn't* render as a link in an HTML context unless you do `echo html_entity_decode($value)`. Without `html_entity_decode()`, it's harmless, and HTML Purifier knows this. There's no reason for it to analyse well-escaped HTML; semantically, it's just text.

### When should you use HTML Purifier?

However, since you're using HTML Purifier on fields like "first name" and "last name", I suspect you don't actually want to use HTML Purifier, though you may not realise this.

**HTML Purifier's purpose is to allow *some* HTML safely**, and it should be used as you **output** your data into the HTML context:

```
// example:
echo $purifier->purify(html_entity_decode($custmer_data['firstname']));
// '--> outputs `<a>L</a>`
```

But that also means that if you have no interest in preserving **any** HTML from your input (you probably *don't* want to enable people to use HTML formatting on their first and last names), HTML Purifier is *not the right tool* for the job - you will want to use [**htmlspecialchars()**](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead. (This, too, is something you should do as you output your data onto the webpage. When you save the values into your *database*, on the other hand, you will want to use prepared statements, or something like [**mysqli_real_escape_string()**](https://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).)

In general, both intent and context are both pivotally important when choosing how to escape or sanitise one's data. Think about *where* you are putting the data and *what* you want to allow or prevent.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying @pinkgothic. 
Please check that before the use of HTMLPurify library the result is fine but i want to remove all tags except the allowed html-tags(script-tag is also not set in the allow-tags) in the $allowedElements array, that's why i want to use HTMLPurifier library because it takes all the $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST at once and filter them and return the required result.  I don't want to filter the form's fields one by one or not go with the loop !  So finally HTMLPurifier is not removing script-tag and/or any inline script which can be harmful.

Comment: @gopalsharma You need to understand that `&lt;a onclick=...&gt;` is not the same as `<a onclick=...>`. HTML Purifier absolutely will handle the latter case. It doesn't care about the former and it shouldn't - there's nothing harmful about it. That said, as I explained, please reconsider your use-case, because HTML Purifier does not sound like the right tool for what you are trying to achieve.